# Modified Futoshiki

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image]

- This is a modified [Futoshiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futoshiki)
- Place the numbers 1 to 5 such that each row, and column contains each of the digits 1 to 5.
- Squares with same color, contains each of the digits 1 to 5 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution, it was kinda easy, waiting for more:

> [image]

Comment: you are right! wait till tomorrow for the green check.

Comment: ^vote with a note: This solution would probably get more approval if it were to show a couple of intermediate stages, especially those that were not straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this to expand upon the logical contradiction I spotted which forces the unique solution.

> [image: futoshiki-1]
>
>  These are simple giveways.
>
>  The green 5 because 5 can't be on a less than, and the middle green is less than by proxy. The same proxy forces the 1 on  the top row.
>
>  The 1 in the blue is now bottom row, and cannot be left because of the equals. This completes the 1's.
>
>  The 5 in the blue is on the left, and so with the equals (row 4 column 3= row 3 column 4), the 5 in the bottom  row is in the middle, and this forces the 5 on column 5.

**Next**

> [image: futoshiki-2]
>
>  We notice X is either 2 or 3. If Y is the other one, then 4 is bottom right, and row 4 column 4 by the equals. so row 3 ends with either 2 3 or 3 2.
>
>  The blue of the top row is also 4, as is the remaining green, and so the middle blue is 5.
>
>  However, this means the remaining bottom left blue, Z, cannot be 1 2 3 4 or 5.
>
>  **Therefore Y is 4**.